# When did India become a major trading center?

Tags: india, trade, contemporary-history

As stated [on this site](http://www.facts-about-india.com/Geography-facts-about-india.php), India is unique in that it has easy sea trading routes to every continent, and is therefore a major trading center. When did India become one— during British occupation, after independence, or during some other period?

Comment: There is evidence that indicates that Indus Valley Civilization had an active trade going on with Mesopotamia, FWIW. Now, is *having sea trading routes to every continent* the only criterion for a country to be a major trading center?

Comment: @taninamdar: Rome also had active trade with India.  There are maps showing trade routes as far as Sri Lanka.  And of course Alexander tried to conquer it.

Comment: What's the definition of "major trading center"? I'd also doubt that India has always had "easy sea trading routes to every continent" or that it is "unique" in this respect.

Comment: I do not think you can qualify India as a "trading center". India is **BIG**. A center is, almost by definition, concentrated. Some cities or areas in the coast or where land rutes passed by could have become trading hubs, but that is not "India".

Comment: And, to support @SteveBird comment, any geographical advantage India has is far from "unique". In relationship with the seas, Sri Lanka is geographically located almost exactly, and the Malacca Straits are a way more natural "trading center".

Comment: @jamesqf Of course. Indus valley is just the oldest example.

Comment: @Steve Bird: Also, I have the impression (though I admit my knowledge is lacking) that the various countries of India were never that much into ocean travel.  That is, it was mainly the Persians, Arabs, &c who sailed to India from the west, and the people of Indonesia & the Malays who came from the east to trade, rather than Indian vessels going to those places.

Comment: @jamesqf At the risk of converting the comment section into discussion, I would like to note that [Chola Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chola_Navy) was a very powerful navy in the waters around India in the high middle ages.

Answer (score 1):

India is far from unique in being a major trade center. The author is being very liberal in their definition of "unique".

But India's status as a major trade center is very ancient. As far back as the Bronze Age, there was [brisk trade between the Indus Valley and Mesopotamia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Ocean_trade), sometimes via sea. There are [documents from 1st century CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periplus_of_the_Erythraean_Sea) describing India as a major trade destination, linked to Egypt, Rome and China. Ancient trade routes with India included the [Silk Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silk_Road) and the [Incense Route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incense_Route). When the [spice trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spice_trade) became prominent, Columbus tried going West and thought he reached India. India was [colonised by many European powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonial_India), due to its favourable position for trade.